# Radio button value displaying JS function doesn't work after legally changing variables names

Tags: javascript, html

I have coded a function `showRadioValue()` in JavaScript which displays a value of radio button. It perfectly worked. But after I changed names of variables (from `radVal` to `ans6`) and function's name to `checkQ6()` , it mysteriously stopped working! Why? Here is the code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Radio test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Question 6</h2>
      <p style="text-align: center;">We  _______  two dogs and a cat.</p> 

<form name="option" style="text-align: center;">
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="have">have<br>
  <input type="radio" name="option" value="is having"> is having<br>
</form>

<p style="text-align: center;" ><button onclick="checkQ6();">Test radio</button></p>

<script>
/*
function showRadioValue() { // previous perfectly working function
    var radVal = document.querySelector('input[name = "option"]:checked').value;
    alert(radVal);
}
*/
function checkQ6() { // the function where just ans6 variable name and function name is changed and which does not work
  var ans6 = document.querySelector('input[name = "option"]:checked').value;
  alert(ans6);

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: close the function with brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function bracket is not closed. You can see these errors in your browser console.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it is the mistake. I'm using Sublime Text 3 editor. I didn't show me the mistake by some reason.